# Python: Building a list comprehension that grows a list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to write some python that will take an existing list, and create a new list containing two entries for every entry in the original.

Example: Every entry should produce two new entries: x+1, and 3x.

```
a = [1]
a = [2, 3]
a = [3, 6, 4, 9]
a = [4, 9, 7, 18, 5, 12, 10, 27]
```

What code could be entered to produce the desired output:

```
a = [1]
for i in range(3):
    a = ???
```

I have tried:

```
a = [(x+1, 3*x) for x in a]
```

... but this was incorrect because the first iteration gives a list containing a single tuple:

```
a = [(2, 3)]
```

... and a subsequent iteration does not work.

In addition to the answer, some explanation into the thought process that produces the answer would be most helpful.

**EDIT:** If anyone can give me some insight as to why my question is receiving close votes, I would appreciate that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a pretty efficient solution that uses [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> a = [1]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable((x+1, x*3) for x in a))
[2, 3]
>>> a = [2, 3]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable((x+1, x*3) for x in a))
[3, 6, 4, 9]
>>> a = [3, 6, 4, 9]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable((x+1, x*3) for x in a))
[4, 9, 7, 18, 5, 12, 10, 27]
>>>
```

The links provided should explain everything except the `list(...)` part.  I did that so the results were lists and not something like `<itertools.chain object at 0x01815370>`.

---

**Edit in response to comment:**

Yes, you can chain as many `chain objects` as you want and then convert the whole thing to a list in the end.  See a demonstration below:

```
>>> a = [3, 6, 4, 9]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable((chain.from_iterable((x+1, x*3) for x in a), chain.from_iterable((x+1, x*3) for x in a))))
[4, 9, 7, 18, 5, 12, 10, 27, 4, 9, 7, 18, 5, 12, 10, 27]
>>>
```

Comment: Is it possible to chain chains together without first forcing each intermediate result to a list -- and only force the final result to a list?  Will this be more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

```
def somefunc(n):
  if not n:
    return [1]
  else:
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([(i+1, 3*i) for i in somefunc(n-1)]))
```

Output:

```
In [20]: somefunc(3)
Out[20]: [4, 9, 7, 18, 5, 12, 10, 27]

In [21]: somefunc(2)
Out[21]: [3, 6, 4, 9]

In [22]: somefunc(1)
Out[22]: [2, 3]
```